# How to understand the function definitions of curry/uncurry

Tags: haskell

A definition about curry/uncurry(schönfinkel/unschönfinkel) from http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/lectures/02-lists.html,

```
schönfinkel :: ((a,b) -> c) -> a -> b -> c
schönfinkel f x y = f (x,y)

unschönfinkel :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a,b) -> c
unschönfinkel f (x,y) = f x y
```

but I think these function definitions above should be:

```
schönfinkel :: ((a,b) -> c) -> a -> b -> c
schönfinkel f (x,y) = f x y
-- schönfinkel(curry) converts an uncurried function 
-- (f (x,y), its type signature is (a,b) -> c)  
-- to a curried function
-- (f x y, its type signature is  a -> b -> c) 

unschönfinkel :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a,b) -> c
unschönfinkel f x y = f (x,y)
-- unschönfinkel(uncurry) converts a curried function  
-- (f x y , its type signature is a -> b -> c) 
-- to an uncurried function
-- (f (x,y), its type signature is (a,b) -> c)
```

Please could someone give me a simple explanation ?

Comment: In `schönfinkel`, if `f` has type `(a,b) -> c`then you can't apply it to 2 arguments as you've done. And you pattern match on a tuple but the type says there are two more arguments, neither of which is a tuple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably misread / misunderstood the initial code, a proper indentation is probably sufficient to get it right:

```
schönfinkel :: ((a,b) -> c) -> a -> b -> c
schönfinkel    f               x    y =  f (x,y)

unschönfinkel :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a,b) -> c
unschönfinkel    f                (x,y) =  f x y
```

Now, let's open ghci and tried a few things:

```
>>> let schönfinkel f x y = f (x,y)

>>> let toBeCurried (x,y) = x ++ y
>>> :t toBeCurried
toBeCurried :: ([a], [a]) -> [a]

>>> :t schönfinkel toBeCurried
schönfinkel toBeCurried :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

Look at the unformal definition you gave and you'll see that it matches the behaviour of `schönfinkel`.

Comment: Please confirm if my understanding is right:
f (x,y) (the function body of schönfinkel) doesn't mean it is a FUNCTION, which just is one VAULE of f with the tuple (x,y). am I right?

Comment: On the right part, `f (x,y)` is the application of the function `f` given in parameter to the tuple `(x,y)` composed of the two last parameters of `schöfinkel`. According to the signature of `f`, `f (x,y)` is interpreted as a "value" of type `c`.

Answer (score -5):

Here is a small piece of explanation about curry from Groovy In Action by Dierk & Co

The basic idea is to take a function with multiple parameters
and transform it into a function with fewer parameters by fixing some of the values. A classic example is to choose some arbitrary value n and transform a function that sums two parameters into a function that takes a single parameter and adds n to it.

Groovy has a built-in Closure's method called ***curry*** which takes arbitrary values to bind to closures arguments and return the clone of closure after being bound the values to the respective arguments. Please refer the below link for detailed understanding

[Groovy functional programming](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Functional+Programming+with+Groovy)